# Swift: Determine iOS Screen size

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to use Swift code to properly position items in my app for no matter what the screen size is. For example, if I want a button to be 75% of the screen wide, I could do something like `(screenWidth * .75)` to be the width of the button. I have found that this could be determined in Objective-C by doing

```
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
```

Unfortunately, I am unsure of how to convert this to Swift. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 812, accepted):

**In Swift 5.0**

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

Pay attention that `UIScreen.main` will be deprecated in future version of iOS. So we can use `view.window.windowScene.screen`.

**Swift 4.0**

```
// Screen width.
public var screenWidth: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
}

// Screen height.
public var screenHeight: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}
```

**In Swift 3.0**

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
```

**In older swift:**
Do something like this:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
```

then you can access the width and height like this:

```
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
```

if you want 75% of your screen's width you can go:

```
let screenWidth = screenSize.width * 0.75
```

Comment: Of course you don't need the semi-colons (I know the habit from years of C coding :-) ) and you can omit :CGRect and write let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds and screenSize will infer the type from the assignment.

Comment: one must be careful since this solution doesn't take a device orientation into account. in landscape width and height are swapped

Comment: how can we adjust the size if the device is rotated

Comment: @pprevalon if width < height

Comment: Swift 3 is UIScreen.main.bounds, not UIScreen.main().bounds

Comment: let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

Comment: it should be
let screenWidth = screenSize.size.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.size.height

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'UIScreen'.... how do I get access to that class? I'm new to swift

Comment: @Robbie Did you import `UIKit`? I think that you have imported `Foundation`.

Comment: Thanks goppinath... new to all these imports. now I'm starting to get it

Comment: This does not work with Split View. The app is in Split View yet still returns as if it's taking the full screen of the iPad.

Comment: It seems that `UIScreen.main.bounds` is deprecated, anyone have an alternative, please?

Comment: `view.window.windowScene.screen` is NOT an alternative because frequently you need to know screen size inside your view when it is not added to hierarchy (and its window property is nil). You can pass window outside but then you need to split your view preparation into 2 chunks that is not convenient.