# Adding constraints to make images 1/4 the screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

Hi I am trying to get 4 rectangles to be each 1/4 of the screen size for each IPhone size from 4 to 6.

I have tried adding constraints and setting the rectangles to equal height but still haven't succeeded.

Is there an easy way to set to set this?

Thank you

Comment: a very good tuto to do that : http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2 :)

Comment: Get the screen/window size then divide it by /4  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110762/swift-determine-ios-screen-size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the `equal heights` constraint to every rectangle (from the rectangle to the view, which has the exact height of the screen), and then click on the constraint, and set the multiplier to 1:4.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice animation. What app are you using to create it?

Comment: @vacawama I'm using LICEcap.

Comment: @Dániel-Nagy Thanks! LICEcap looks like an effective tool for better communication.