# iOS game is zoomed in on iOS 7 simulator, but everything is fine on iOS 8 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am attempting to create an iOS game using xCode but I've run into a small issue. When I run my game on the iOS simulator that is iOS 7 the entire screen is zoomed and I can barely see anything. However everything runs perfectly when I run the game on the simulator using iOS 8. At first I thought it was because I use

```
sprite.yScale = 0.8
```

instead of

```
sprite.yScale = self.frame.size.height*x
```

Although that doesn't seem to be the case since after I changed that the problem still persisted.

Comment: Did you already check the simulator zoom level? Might not be your code at all.

Comment: @MilesAlden yeah I checked that already

Comment: ic. Do you have more code context and have you tested that `self.frame.size.height` is the same both times? Sorry for simple answers, but always gotta check the simplest ones first. :D

Comment: @MilesAlden it's okay I understand, I've tested the `self.frame.size.height` method a lot of times but still no luck.

Comment: Gotcha. Is the device scale the same each time? And can you post a little more code context?

Comment: Maybe try to get the screen size by some other way, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110762/swift-determine-ios-screen-size. I don't think this will solve it but you could print the results of both to see whether they actually work

Comment: @MilesAlden what kind of context do you need? I haven't really done much at this point, I think it's too early for me to be running into a problem

Comment: @LinusG. when I multiply the screen size to 0.x everything gets bigger but when I multiply the screen size by a whole number it zooms out, also some things seem to be missing when its zoomed out if that could help find a solution