# how to set leading and trailing constraint for a xib used as titleView

Tags: swift, constraints, uinavigationbar, titleview

I have Xib file with two labels, left and right. left one has 0 on leading and right 0 on trailing. in between a >= 15 constraint. This view is used as title view in a navigation bar. My Question is: How to set this xib in order to get left label close to leftItem and right one close to the rightItem?

how the xib is called

```
headerVC = HeaderViewController(nibName: "HeaderViewController", bundle: nil)
```

how the xib is filled

```
    navigationItem.titleView = headerVC?.view
                headerVC?.lbl1.text = name
                headerVC?.lbl2.text = balance

//test purpose
                    //        headerVC?.backgroundColor = .red
                    //this try of mine not working
                    let leftWidth = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.width ?? 0.0
        let rightWidth = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.width ?? 0.0
        let sides = leftWidth + rightWidth
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
//        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
//            headerVC?.view.width = screenWidth - leftWidth - rightWidth
        headerVC?.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth - sides).isActive = true
//        ])
```

solution, related to the answer below and to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110762/swift-determine-ios-screen-size) answer

```
        headerVC?.backgroundColor = .red
        headerVC?.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        headerVC?.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth * 0.75).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraints configure the title view to be as small as possible while still showing the labels. If you want the title view to be wider, you will have to add a width constraint making it wider. The title view cannot "see" the left and right items in the nav bar in any way; you'll just have to figure out what the width should be, yourself, and set it.

Here's an example; the title view is given a width constraint of 100 and 250, respectively.

[image]

[image]

So for example the second one is

```
let v = UIView()
v.backgroundColor = .red
v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
self.navigationItem.titleView = v
```

Comment: but, the width should be dynamic right? with is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: What I'm saying is that it isn't dynamic. It is completely self-contained; it isn't aware of its surroundings.

Comment: I see, what do you think about calculating the window's width?

Comment: Absolutely, just remember you are basically guessing. :) Give it a shot and see if you can get satisfactory results. Of course if we rotate you're going to have to cope with that, but let's cross that bridge later.

Comment: I updated the question with my new try, but not working.

Comment: I updated the answer with screen shot that shows this kind of thing does work.

Comment: sure, did so - remember, it's just a proof of concept, but it does prove the concept

Comment: added a solution starting from yours. What do you think about it? if it is good enough, what about crossing that bridge?